# Q&A English Auction- if a wallets under bids then provides a valid bid, why doesn't it count the second good bid?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

if you set up the english auction with three wallets and do the following:

1. Wallet 1 min bid 10
2. Wallet 2 bids 15
3. wallet 3 bids 9
4. wallet 3 bids 20
5. wallet 1 closes
   It will got to wallet 2 and wallet three's second bid never shows up. Is this a bug or intended?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a bug in the off-chain code. In step 3 in your example, wallet 3 bids under the minimum. This throws an error which triggers a bug that causes all subsequent bids from wallet 3 to be ignored.

It happens on [lines 280-281](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week01/src/Week01/EnglishAuction.hs#L280) when the error is thrown.

If you replace those 2 lines with this, it should work:

```
if (bpBid < minBid d) 
  then logError @P.String $ printf "bid lower than minimal bid %d" (minBid d)
  else do
```

Credit to @kindofdev for showing me the fix.